# How to make work install codeigniter on different domain

Tags: codeigniter

I do not know what to choose titles but this is definitely related to CodeIgniter, a few years ago I bought a CMS with CodeIgniter but it can only be used by one domain but if in different domains can not install.

I've changed `$config['base_url']` and `$config['url']` with a new URL but remains blank. but I found the code below which is under unusual

```
$config ['encryption_key'] = "xxxxx"
$config ['global_encryption_key'] = "xxxxx"
```

Is it possible that `global_encryption_key` code in order to restrict the domain can not be used in addition to the first

for example I have used this domain: *ocimblog.me*

Comment: Since we dont know what CMS you bought, Its impossible to answer. Search all config-files after your old domain name, and the database.

Comment: i has search and not found anything else, i bought 2Leep Clone Script form 3fusion, do you want to help me? i will send the script if it can

Comment: why don't you contact 3fusion? If you have a valid license and only want to change the domain, they'll be happy to help you. It is not supposed to install other places without paying for a new license.